# How do you bind your dynamic ASP.NET DropDownListFor() with the stored value in the database using knockout data binding in the Edit form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, knockout-mvc

I have a working Form which dynamically fetches the data from the database, updates it and stores it in the database.However, I have an issue in dynamically binding a dropdown picklist to the current value stored in the database while Editing.

The issue I face is with the picklist dropdown field, when it is loaded in the Edit form, it is not bound to the current value of that field in the database, as a work around to it, I create a disabled field with the current value in the database, and a second dropdown field for the picklist. The edit form on the ajax post picks up the value in the dropdown field and stores it into the database.
Now you can guess the issue is that when the user does not even touch the dropdown field from the picklist, the default value gets posted and gets stored in the database hence editing it without the user noticing.

```
<div class="row" id="editProspectMeasuredStructurFormDiv" data-bind="with:EditModel">


@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ProspectMeasuredStructure", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-group", @id = "editForm" })){
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeasuredStructureId, new { @class = "form-control", data_bind = "value: MeasuredStructureText", disabled = "disabled" })
<label>The MeasuredStructureis listed as:</label>

     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeasuredStructureId, new SelectList(Model.MeasuredStructures, "MeasuredStructureId", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "editMeasuredStructureId", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MeasuredStructureId) })
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MeasuredStructureId)
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-action" value="Submit" id="submitEditMeasuredStructure" data-bind="click: function(){$root.EditMeasuredStructure();}" />
}
</div>
```

```
 var prospectMeasuredStructureModel = function (parent, prospectMeasuredStructureId, prospectId, prospectText, measuredStructureId, measuredStructureText{
 var self = this;
        self.ProspectMeasuredStructureId = ko.observable(prospectMeasuredStructureId);
        self.ProspectId = ko.observable(prospectId);
        self.ProspectText = ko.observable(prospectText);
        self.MeasuredStructureId = ko.observable(measuredStructureId);
        self.MeasuredStructureText = ko.observable(measuredStructureText);
        self.EditModel = ko.observable();
}



var prospectMeasuredStructureViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.ProspectMeasuredStructureId = ko.observable();
        self.ProspectId = ko.observable();
        self.ProspectText = ko.observable();
        self.MeasuredStructureId = ko.observable();
        self.MeasuredStructureText = ko.observable();
        self.EditModel = ko.observable();

        self.EditMeasuredStructure = function () {
            self.ProspectMeasuredStructureId = $('#editProspectMeasuredStructureId').val();
            self.ProspectId = $('#hfProspectId').val();
            self.MeasuredStructureId = $('#editMeasuredStructureId').val();
            self.Address = $('#editAddress').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit", "ProspectMeasuredStructure")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(self),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        self.GetMeasuredStructures();
                        $('#editForm').hide();
                        alert("Edit Worked");
                    } else {
                        alert("Edit did not work");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ContentResult GetMeasuredStructures([FromBody] ProspectMeasuredStructureViewModel measuredStructureVM)
        {
            //Guid ProspectId = Guid.Parse(measuredStructure.ProspectId);
            var prospectMS = repository.Get(c => !c.Delete && c.ProspectId== measuredStructureVM.ProspectId);
            foreach (var item in prospectMS)
            {
                ProspectMeasuredStructureViewModel pVM = new ProspectMeasuredStructureViewModel();
                pVM.ProspectMeasuredStructureId = item.ProspectMeasuredStructureId;
                pVM.ProspectId = item.ProspectId;
                pVM.ProspectText = listManager.GetProspect(item.ProspectId).Name;
                pVM.MeasuredStructureId = item.MeasuredStructureId;
                pVM.MeasuredStructureText = listManager.GetMeasuredStructure(item.MeasuredStructureId).Name;
                prospectMeasuredStructureVModels.Add(pVM);
            }
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prospectMeasuredStructureVModels),
                ContentType = "application/json"
            };
        }
```

I am not sure how to bind the `@Html.DropDownListFor()` with the saved value which was added when the user first added the measured structure. As I said before, it shows the picklist correctly, what it does not do is "show the currently saved value as the first value". Hence it causes the default value to be saved to the database.

Kindly let me know if there is more code, if that needs to be posted, as I tried to take as many snippets as I thought were sufficient to explain my issue.

Comment: one fix is to use if statement in the javascript side, to check the value, if is it not the default value, then post the update. However, you should use the Event Handler to control the user input. For instance, don't let it post until the user stops editing (typing, choosing ..etc) or think of way based on your logic and user experience  to overcome it , just don't let it open-ended, either post or no post.

Comment: @iSR5 There are other form fields as well, which might be edited. So the post does end up taking place. Isnt there a way to bind the dropdown with the value of the actual value in the database along with the `other` picklist values.

Comment: yes there is, you can bind the list to the actual table, and on change event, you recreate the query based on the selected value, which will bind the new dropdownlist from its table.

Comment: @iSR5 can you show me how its done ?

Comment: yes, but I won't use your code, just to give you an idea on how it works, then you can bind the idea to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was bind the dropdown list with the ID and that translated as the default value of the drop down list along with other picklist values in my view where the DropDownList was being declared.

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeasuredStructureId, new SelectList(Model.MeasuredStructures, "MeasuredStructureId", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "editMeasuredStructureId", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MeasuredStructureId),data_bind = " value: MeasuredStructureId" })
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MeasuredStructureId)
```